# Unexpected results when calling prototype function in JS

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
function Shape(color) {
    this.color = color;
}

Shape.prototype.draw = function() {
    return "Drew shape";
};

function Circle(color, radius) {
    Shape.apply(this, arguments);
    this.radius = radius;
}

Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Circle.prototype.draw = function() {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).draw() + ", which was a circle";
};

var c = new Circle("red", 5);
```

This mostly works as expected, except calling c.draw():

```
c.draw(); // outputs "Drew shape, which was a circle, which was a circle"
```

This calls the base class's draw() as expected, but seems to also invoke an extra recursive call to itself!? What's going on?

John Resig presents this as the way to implement Super Methods, http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/, but if you add a console.log() to Norris's kick you'll see that it too is called twice for each explicit call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that the prototype of `this` in `Circle.prototype.draw` will be `Circle.prototype` itself. So, it will return `Circle.prototype` object again. So, the call

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(this).draw()
```

will be reduced to

```
Circle.prototype.draw()
```

So the same function will be called again, but this time the `this` will refer to the `Circle.prototype`, whose prototype is the `Shape.prototype` object. So,

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Circle.prototype).draw()
```

will evaluate to

```
Shape.prototype.draw()
```

The inner most call will be evaluated first, so it returns `Drew Shape` first and since the `Circle`'s `draw` function gets called twice, it prints `which was a circle` twice.

To fix this, you just need to call the parent's `draw`, like this

```
return Object.getPrototypeOf(Circle.prototype).draw() + ", which was a circle";
```

We can realize the prototype chain like this

```
+------------------+
|       this       |
+------------------+
|     __proto__    |+-
+------------------+  |
                      |  +------------------+
                       -+| Circle.prototype |
                         +------------------+
                         |     __proto__    |+-
                         +------------------+  |
                                               |  +------------------+
                                                -+|  Shape.prototype |
                                                  +------------------+
                                                  |     __proto__    |
                                                  +------------------+
```